# variable posted from angular to php using $http.post() is not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http

I posted a variable from a angularjs controller to a php file in the same folder using $http.post() method. But in the php page I am able to retrieve the variable. The variable is being undefined.

Here is the angular code

```
$scope.checkout = function(){
         $http({
         url:"checkout.php",
         method : 'POST',
         data :{
            'total':$scope.total
        },

        headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        window.location.href = 'checkout.php'
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       console.log("not done");
});
    }
```

and here is the php code

```
<?php
$_SESSION['bill_amount'] = $_POST['total'];
echo $_SESSION['bill_amount'];
?>
```

But I am getting the error that total is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I created a middle page called middleware.php where I am storing the post data to session variables and on success I am redirecting to checkout.php and using the post values through session variables.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending data but Angular by default send it as in `JSON` format and you need to decode the JSON so in your php file decode the `JSON` by using `json_decode` function.The full code is given below:

```
<?php
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
 $total = $data->total; // $_POST['total'];
 $_SESSION['bill_amount'] = $total;
?>
```

Comment: No its not working..Trying to get property of non-object is the error its showing...See on success I am redirecting to that page does $http.post() has no effect after redirection